Dirichlet Problem with $L^p$ Boundary Data
I am seeking a proof of the following result related to the Dirichlet problem with $L^p$ boundary data. I am not quite sure how to approach the proof. Does anyone know where I might find such a proof or have any resources that could assist me?
Theorem
Let $ B = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n : |x| < 1\} $ and $ 1 < p < \infty $. Assume that for every $ f \in C(\partial B) $, the following problem
$$
\begin{cases}
    \Delta u = 0 & \text{in } B \\
    u = f & \text{on } \partial B
\end{cases}
$$
has a unique solution $ u \in C^2(B) \cap C(\overline{B}) $ satisfying
$$
    \|Nu\|_{L^p(\partial B)} \leq C\|f\|_{L^p(\partial B)}.
$$
I want to show that for any $ g \in L^p(\partial B) $, there exists a unique solution to the problem:
$$
\begin{cases}
    \Delta v = 0 & \text{in } B \\
    v(x) \xrightarrow[N.T.]{x \to P} g & \text{for almost every } P \in \partial B
\end{cases}
$$
Here, "N.T." stands for "non-tangential".
Furthermore, this solution fulfill:
$$
    \|Nv\|_{L^p(\partial B)} \leq C\|g\|_{L^p(\partial B)}.
$$

What is $Nu$? And what do you mean $v\to g$ with the subscript non-tangential?
